How can I use react hook forms with dynamical array based on back end response
I have a service that retrieves an array of elements from my backend application made with NodeJS, the array is something like this:

{
  "ods": "Fin de la pobreza",
  "metas": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "titulo": "Fin de la pobreza",
      "descripcion": "Erradicar la pobreza extrema para todas las personas en todo el mundo para 2030 es un objetivo fundamental de la Agenda 2030 para el desarrollo sostenible.",
      "idOds": 1,
      "createdAt": "2024-09-10T16:47:31.947Z",
      "updatedAt": "2024-09-10T16:47:31.947Z",
      "ods": {
        "id": 1,
        "posicion": 1,
        "titulo": "Fin de la pobreza",
        "descripcion": "Erradicar la pobreza extrema para todas las personas en todo el mundo para 2030 es un objetivo fundamental de la Agenda 2030 para el desarrollo sostenible.",
        "urlImagen": "https://www.un.org/sustainabledevelopment/es/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2016/01/S_SDG_Icons-01-01.jpg",
        "createdAt": "2024-08-21T16:41:52.901Z",
        "updatedAt": "2024-08-21T16:41:52.901Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
...

Approximately, I have around 16 objects with N quantity of "metas" that I want to display as the following on mi application

I want to be able to use react hook forms to select N quantity of "metas" and store them in my database, but also, If my element already has "metas" assigned, I want them to be checked on my checkboxes. So far, I have this block of code but it is not working as expected
        {
          metas?.map((objetivo, idx) => (
            <Box>
              <Typography variant='body2'>
                {objetivo.ods}
              </Typography>
              <Box sx={{
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column',
              }}>
                {
                  objetivo.metas.map((meta, idx) => (
                    <Controller
                      key={meta.id}
                      {...methods.register(`metas.${meta.id}`)}
                      //register whole object
                      control={methods.control}
                      render={({ field: { value, onChange }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
                        <FormControlLabel
                          control={
                            <Checkbox
                              size='small'
                              icon={<PanoramaFishEye />}
                              checkedIcon={< CheckCircle />}
                              onChange={onChange}
                              value={meta.id}
                            />}
                          label={
                            <Tooltip title={meta.descripcion}>
                              <Typography>
                                {meta.titulo}
                              </Typography>
                            </Tooltip>
                          }
                          sx={{
                            borderRadius: '50px',
                            border: '1px solid #ccc',
                            p: '1px',
                            pr: '10px',
                            m: '5px',
                          }}
                        />
                      )}
                      defaultValue={false}
                    />
                  ))
                }
              </Box>
            </Box>
          ))
        }

How can I use useFieldArray to save my data?

Checkbox has an attribute "checked" that keeps track of checked values. You can assign the condition that checks if your element already has "metas" assigned or not.
checked={checkMetasAssigned(meta)}. checkMetasAssigned will return true or false
